# I need some to explain to me collocation method and points

Tags: numerical-methods, integral-equations

I have been researching the whole internet for hours just to get a good insight about collocation method and points. I would appreciate if someone could explain these terms in details and give reference.

## UPDATE

I am an undergrad studying Mathematics.

Below is the assignment I was given.

1. Define integral equations
2. Explain collocation methods and points
3. State 4 four examples of integral equation with their exact solution

Comment: Could you give a little more context? Why is this of interest to you? What do you already understand, however incomplete?

Comment: I understand collection methods are used to solve integral equation from the papers I have read. I was given a research assignment by my professor "Numerical solution of integral equations by collocation methods"

Comment: Please add to your post the following information: 1) The assignment you were given in a little more detail, 2) What is your background: did you study integral equations and/or numerical methods before, 3) What do you already know about collocation methods (since you have read a few papers already, you have to know something). This is important, otherwise you would not get an answer which would be both clear enough and complete enough for your purposes

Comment: In addition, hours is definitely not enough time to understand a new subject. It usually takes me days to weeks (sometimes months) of research

Comment: I will do just that now